# Isn't there a OpenCV Cuda function similar to findContours?

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv3.0

There are several OpenCV CPU functions which have a direct CUDA counterpart like `cv::cvtColor` & `cv::cuda::cvtColor`.

But I found no direct or indirect (GPU) Cuda counterpart for `cv::findContours` CPU.

Isn't there a OpenCV Cuda function similar to findContours? Or does findContours work on both `cv::Mat` and `cv::cuda::GpuMat`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, not. Not even in the latest OpenCV 3.2.0 version. But they have this update, as shown here: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/ChangeLog

`findContours` can now find contours on a 32-bit integer image of labels (not only on a black-and-white 8-bit image). This is a step towards more convenient connected component analysis.

Answer (score 1):

No. OpenCV 4.6.0 does not have it.

Nobody has dared to implement this with CUDA for years.